# Can we read file from the the local path in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, file

I have a situation where I have some absolute path say "`E:/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/AnotherFolder/abc.csv`". And my Angular application is in a different folder.

Now I want to read "`abc.csv`" in some method in the Angular application. Is there any way to read "abc.csv" from the path given?

Comment: Angular is a javscript based front-end framework. It can't read files on the hard drive of a user. Maybe you could prompt the user to upload the file and handle it on the back-end?

Comment: I imagine having a serverside script (any language should do) that can access the filesystem would allow you to make a call to it and give you back the data from the file yes

Comment: You'd need a server to run on the file system the file is at (electron) - or get a user to upload that file and do it in a backend